# How to use urandom to generate all possible base64 characters?

Tags: random, cryptography, base64

In a base64 digits you could save up to 6 bits (`2**6 == 64`).

Which means that you could fit 3 bytes in 4 base64 digits.

`64**4 == 2**24`

That's why:

```
0x000000 == 'AAAA'
0xFFFFFF == '////'
```

This means that a random string of 3 bytes is equivalent to a base64 string of 4 characters.

However if I am converting a number of bytes which is not a multiple of 3 in a base64 string, I will not be able to generate all the combination of the base64 string.

Let's take an example:

- If I want a random 7 characters base64 string, I would need to generate 42 random bits (`64**7 == 2**42`).

If I am using urandom to get 5 random bytes I will get only 40 bits (5*8) and if ask for 6 I will get 48 bits (6*8).

Can I ask for 6 bytes and use a mask to short it down to 5 or will it break my random repartition?

One solution:

```
hex(0x123456789012 & 0xFFFFFFFFFF)
'0x3456789012'
```

Another one:

```
hex(0x123456789012 >> 8)
'0x1234567890'
```

What do you think?

Comment: Since you obtain random bytes from urandom, you may also state you are receiving random bits. So you should indeed call for 6 bytes and ignore 6 bits to get 42 bits. Whether you choose to drop the first 6 or the last 6 bits should not matter in this case.

Comment: but you should at least use /dev/random instead of /dev/urandom to enhance your entropy

Comment: If I understand correctly another solution would be always generate multiple of 3 bytes base64 string and cut the string to the number of characters we want to keep?

Comment: If you want to have all bits set in your base64, yes, you should get a multiple of three bytes. Otherwise you should be padding, which is definitely not done with random data.

Comment: *"How to use urandom to generate all possible base64 characters?"* - You don't? I don't understand what this has to do with urandom. If you want (all?) valid base64 encodings for 42 bits, you can generate all those bytes as a counter and encode each one with Base64 (possibly omitting the padding characters). What exactly do you want to achieve? It seems to me you're trying to do something [ass backwards](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/ass-backwards). Perhaps you want to generate 10 random bytes (without padding) and check if they are indeed a valid Base64 encoding?

Comment: No I want to use all the base64 alphabet as a random key and use urandom to generate it while using all the keyspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*base64* strings with 7 characters of length 
is an encode of a file with 5 bytes ( 40 bits: no less, no more )

40%6 = 4

*base64* needs to add `2 more bits`, and then, with `42 bits`, `42%6=0`,
the encode is possible; but, beware:

> " If I want a random 7 characters base64 string, I would need to
>   generate 42 random bits `(64**7 == 2**42)`. "

the 2 additional bits are not random, and are constants; are zero, indeed.

The cardinal number of your key-space doesn't change: is `2**40 = 1099511627776`, not `(64**7 == 2**42)`.

`(64**7 == 2**42)` is the cardinal number of the key-space that contains all possible combinations of 64 chars with length of 7; but, with the last two bits fixed (to zero, in this case, but doesn't matter the value) you don't have all possible combinations.

6 random bytes (48 bits), or 42 random bits, increase your original key-space; you should use 5 random bytes (40 bits), and send it to *base64*

Comment: Yes that's why it doesn't meet my requirement of a ``64**7`` key space.